# How to read blob (pickle) files from GCS in a Google Cloud DataFlow job?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I try to run a DataFlow pipeline remotely which will use a pickle file.
Locally, I can use the code below to invoke the file.

```
with open (known_args.file_path, 'rb') as fp:
     file = pickle.load(fp)
```

However, I find it not valid when the path is about cloud storage(gs://...):

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://.../.pkl'
```

I kind of understand why it is not working but I cannot find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have pickle files in your GCS bucket, then you can **load them as BLOBs** and process them further like in your code (using `pickle.load()`):

```
class ReadGcsBlobs(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        from apache_beam.io.gcp import gcsio
        gcs = gcsio.GcsIO()
        yield (element, gcs.open(element).read())


# usage example:
files = (p
         | "Initialize" >> beam.Create(["gs://your-bucket-name/pickle_file_path.pickle"])
         | "Read blobs" >> beam.ParDo(ReadGcsBlobs())
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

`open()` is the standard Python library function that does not understand Google Cloud Storage paths. You need to use the [Beam `FileSystems` API](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py) instead, which is aware of it and of other filesystems supported by Beam.